# Relay: wetting contacts before using sub-wetting current

Tags: switches, relay, current-measurement, low-voltage

I'm considering using small signal relay for my application since I need to switch shunt resistors to measure currents from 1uA to 10mA (two shunts) with voltages from 0V to 5V.

Now, it's clear for me what and why wetting current is. The relay I'm considering is EE2-3NU surface mount small signal relay. It has a wetting current of 10uA and it wants minimum of 10mV for it.

The question is: Can I apply minimum wetting voltage and current to the relay and then proceed immediately with my sub-wetting currents? For example, the device boots, wets the contacts with fancy current/voltage (min 10uA and min 10mV in my case), and then it does my 1uA current thing (or, say, 5mV applied - I can set either). Will this work? How reliable is this approach?

Comment: It's as reliable as your schematic permits it to be. Have you not considered analogue switches for doing this?

Comment: Your reply is very inconclusive; Will pre-wetting work ok? I did consider analog switches, but I want to control resistance. I have found only ONE multiplexer on the entire mouser to fit that, and it doesn't even cost much, but relay is more precise anyway. I'm considering options.

Comment: My "comment" is a hint followed by a question.

Comment: In instrumentations the relay still reigns, if the actuation count allows it. Or simply the machine gives the message "replace relays in mux board" (it really happens). I'm not sure it would be adequate, it depends on 'how' the relay uses the wetting current. If it's to 'clean' the contact it will be fine but if the contact uses is as a 'bias' to stay linear or whatever you'll lose the advantage when you go under the minimum. Ask the manufacturer for details